# Resharper: To-do items -> Regular Expression

Tags: regex, resharper

What could be the correct **RegEx** to create a new To-do pattern to list all the "Debug." calls from my solution?

This Expression is for the TODO items:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>TODO)(\W|$)(.*)
```

Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working pattern I've found so far is:

```
(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>Debug)(\W|$)(.*)
```

And this is how it looks like in the To-do Explorer:

[image: Resharper's To-do Explorer]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this type of search to work in the To-do Items\To-do Explorer but I was able to find two solutions\workarounds:

1. Remove the . (I haven't been able to escape any character using \ in the Regular expression box) and just search for another word. I am always using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` when I am in the middle of writing code so I just set it to look for `WriteLine`. The To-do Explorer allows you to filter on the items to look at so you can ignore these until you are ready to clean them up.
2. Use the Custom Patterns feature to search for the text that you are interested in. I am currently searching for anything in the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` namespace that is followed by WriteLine and has some number of arguments with it. This comes out to `$debug$.WriteLine($args$);` (you can name the placeholders anything you want). I have this set to the Error level so that these lines show up very visibly in the 'Errors in Solution' window with Solution Wide Analysis on. [This](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/) link gives more information on how to use this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is a bit strange how the Resharper's To-do Explorer works. Finally I managed to use this expression, but it is still not perfect: `(?<=\W|^)(?<TAG>Debug)(\W|$)(.*)` Unfortunately I can't see the rest of the code after `Debug` in the To-do Explorer.